# How to detect which case is true in switch where multiple cases are combined

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```
    switch (selectedRadioVal) {
    case CARD_ORDER_FIELDS:
    case CARD_ORDER_IDS:
        var items = currentSelect.getElementsByTagName("option");
        if (items.length == 0) {
            $('#txtCardOrderField').focus();
            return;
        }
      //something like this:if (CARD_ORDER_FIELDS)do this; else do that;

}
```

As you can see I'm trying to perform the same operation if the value of the switched statement equals CARD_ORDER_FIELDS or CARD_ORDER_IDS, except for the last line. Is it possible to check the current value inside this block and perform some part of the code based on that value?

Comment: if (selectedRadioVal == CARD_ORDER_FIELDS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call an if statement inside the switch:

```
if (selectedRadioVal == CARD_ORDER_FIELDS)
{
   //do something
}
```

---

In full:

```
 switch (selectedRadioVal) {
    case CARD_ORDER_FIELDS:
    case CARD_ORDER_IDS:
        var items = currentSelect.getElementsByTagName("option");
        if (items.length == 0) {
            $('#txtCardOrderField').focus();
            return;
        }
        if (selectedRadioVal == CARD_ORDER_FIELDS)
        {
          //do something
        }    
  }
```

Comment: Really man, that should be this simple. Sometimes I get so stupid.